# How to change the image shown by a GtkImage?

Tags: python, gtk, gtk3, gdkpixbuf

in my program I would like to change an image by clicking a button but I can not find the function

```
class TestGdkPixbuf(Gtk.Window):
    Cover= "image.png"
    Cover2= "image2.png"

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="TestGdkPixbuf")

        mainLayout = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL, spacing=6)


        self.image = GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf.new_from_file_at_size(self.Cover, 250, 250)
        image_renderer = Gtk.Image.new_from_pixbuf(self.image)

        button = Gtk.Button(label='Change')
        button.connect('clicked', self.editPixbuf)

        mainLayout.pack_start(image_renderer, True, True, 0)
        mainLayout.pack_start(button, True, True, 0)

        self.add(mainLayout)

    def editPixbuf(self, button):
        self.image = GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf.new_from_file_at_size(self.Cover2, 250, 250)
        print(self.Cover2)
```

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you've created the Gtk.Image, `image_renderer`, you supplied a pixbuf, `self.image`.

Then on your button callback, you did load an image into a pixbuf but did not update the `image_renderer` with the new pixbuf. You should use Gtk.Image [`set_from_pixbuf`](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gtk-3.0/classes/Image.html#Gtk.Image.set_from_pixbuf).

Try:

```
class TestGdkPixbuf(Gtk.Window):
    Cover= "image.png"
    Cover2= "image2.png"

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="TestGdkPixbuf")

        mainLayout = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL, spacing=6)


        self.image = GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf.new_from_file_at_size(self.Cover, 250, 250)
        self.image_renderer = Gtk.Image.new_from_pixbuf(self.image)

        button = Gtk.Button(label='Change')
        button.connect('clicked', self.editPixbuf)

        mainLayout.pack_start(image_renderer, True, True, 0)
        mainLayout.pack_start(button, True, True, 0)

        self.add(mainLayout)

    def editPixbuf(self, button):
        self.image = GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf.new_from_file_at_size(self.Cover2, 250, 250)
        self.image_renderer.set_from_pixbuf (self.image)
        print(self.Cover2)
```